# W|A or Mathematica for CountryData?

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries

Sometimes W|A gives you something ...

```
WolframAlpha["electricity production of the United States in 2007", "Result"]
```

[image]

... not available in the WDF

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", {"ElectricityProduction", 2007}]
```

[image]

Other times, the opposite seems to apply - say for more recent data in WDF ...

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", "ElectricityProduction"]
```

[image]

... whereas in W|A

```
WolframAlpha["electricity production of the United States in 2014", "Result"]
```

[image]

... or at least I'd assumed it was more recent and this now conflicts with the earlier W|A output?

```
CountryData["UnitedStates", "ElectricityProduction", "Date"]
```

[image]

Are multiple data sources being used here or is this a bug?

Comment: I would guess that it is indeed an issue with multiple sources; I cannot figure out what else it could be, and the way you checked the dates for both of the data requests should guarantee it. It could be that because W|A runs on an offsite computer, it is told to take an average of all the available values, whereas Mathematica would take the first available value as a good enough approximation to reduce the computing time required? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/CountryDataSourceInformation.html

Answer (score 5):

Based on the documentation, I would say that this is a bug.  Note, however, that you can perhaps get at the data you want via the call

```
EntityValue[Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
 EntityProperty["Country", "ElectricityTotal", "Date" -> 2007]]
```

though the relationship between "ElectricityTotal" and "ElectricityProduction" is less than clear.  I would file this as a feedback to Wolfram.